# Update column values using a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below and need to update the `Value` column for the factor ido. I want to update the ido value by doing the following

```
   ido Value = top Value - sos Value
```

for each date and method type.

Current table:

```
   DateP        Factor     Value     Method
  ------------------------------------------
   2017-01-01   top        23        w
   2017-01-01   sos        15        w
   2017-01-01   ido        20        w
   2017-01-01   top        29        M
   2017-01-01   sos        10        M
   2017-01-01   ido        2         M
   2017-02-02   top        101       w
   2017-02-02   sos        60        w
   2017-02-02   ido        20        w
```

So hopefully the table below makes it clear what I am trying to achieve

Desired table after updates:

```
   DateP        Factor     Value     Method
   -----------------------------------------
   2017-01-01   top        23        w
   2017-01-01   sos        15        w
   2017-01-01   ido        8         w
   2017-01-01   top        29        M
   2017-01-01   sos        10        M
   2017-01-01   ido        19        M
   2017-02-02   top        101       w
   2017-02-02   sos        60        w
   2017-02-02   ido        41        w
```

Comment: this changes just one of the `ido` rows, the rest don't follow your rule....why?

Comment: ah apologies, copy paste error

Comment: updated the values, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: What's factor that top, sos and ido in the same group? Or your table will be ordered exactly like the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE A
SET a.[Value] = b.TopValue - b.SosValue
FROM dbo.YourTable a
INNER JOIN (SELECT  DateP, 
                    Method, 
                    MIN(CASE WHEN Factor = 'top' THEN [Value] END) TopValue,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN Factor = 'sos' THEN [Value] END) SosValue
            FROM dbo.YourTable
            GROUP BY DateP, 
                     Method) b
    ON a.DateP = b.DateP
    AND A.Method = b.Method
WHERE a.Factor = 'ido'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when factor = 'top' then value
                      when factor = 'sos' then - value
                 end) over (partition by date, method) as new_value
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = new_value
    where method = 'ido';
```